# Setting Active Directory user login name post Windows 2000 with System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, userprincipal

How can I set the user logon name outlined in red from below screenshot (post Windows 2000) using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`?

[image]

Users are created from the [`UserPrincipal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx) object but I'm not seeing any property or mutator method to do so:

```
using (var user = new UserPrincipal(context)) {
    user.SamAccountName = samAccountName;
    user.GivenName = fname;
    user.Surname = lname;
    user.EmailAddress = email;
    user.SetPassword(password);
    user.Enabled = true;
    user.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:  `user.UserPrincipalName`

SamAccountName is the pre-Win2000 name.

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677605(v=vs.85).aspx)